# Using GeoServer REST Configuration to add a datastore

Tags: postgis, geoserver, rest

I have used the example from the [Geoserver REST Docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples-curl.html#adding-a-postgis-database) to add a datastore from at PostGIS database. 
I have used the following xml doc to add the new datastore:

```
<dataStore>
  <name>my_datastore</name>
  <connectionParameters>
    <host>localhost</host>
    <port>5432</port>
    <database>postgis</database>
    <user>username</user>
    <passwd>secret</passwd>
    <schema>public</schema>
    <dbtype>postgis</dbtype>
  </connectionParameters>
</dataStore>
```

The datastore was created with the connection parameters as I expected. But the **datastore.xml** created looks different from the datastore that I have created with the **GeoServer Web Admin**. 
The connection parameters I am missing is:

- Connection timeout
- validate connections
- max connections
- Loose bbox
- Expose primary keys
- fetch size
- Max open prepared statements
- preparedStatements
- Estimated extends
- min connections

So my question is: What are the above mentioned connection parameters corresponding xml elements?

EDIT: I am using GeoServer 2.1-RC1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify them exactly like they are specified in the datastore.xml. The REST api allows for multiple syntaxes in connectionParameters. The following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
<port>5432</port>
<entry key="port">5432</entry>
```

You will find a description of what those additional parameters mean in the [user guide](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/postgis.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can include any element in the datastore.xml file using the same format. All the RESTConfig does is copy your POSTed file to the datastore folder.